# Login Facebook SDK 4 Android

Tags: android, facebook

I have this code ....

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {
List<String> permissionNeeds = Arrays.asList("email", "user_birthday",
        "user_hometown");
private LoginButton loginButton;
CallbackManager callbackManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this);
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    loginButton.setReadPermissions(permissionNeeds);

    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager,
            new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(LoginResult result) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Log.e("MainActivity", "Facebook session Opened.");

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Log.e("MainActivity", "Facebook session Cancel.");

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(FacebookException error) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Log.e("MainActivity", "Facebook session Error.");

                }
            });

}}
```

But i dont know what happens when i finish the login , because when i see my logs i dont see my logs `"Log.e("MainActivity", "Facebook session opened.");"` , when i finish this process i need open other activity... Help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this link will show you how to make login facebook SDK v.4
https://youtu.be/myWu-q8Q2NA